Column not working in toga python for android
import toga
from toga.style import Pack
from toga.style.pack import COLUMN
#import requests
#import time

class StartApp(toga.App):
    def startup(self):
        self.main_window = toga.MainWindow(title=self.name)
        self.join_box = toga.Box()
        self.join_lbl = toga.Label('Join', style=Pack(color='black', direction=COLUMN, padding_top=100, padding_left=150, font_size=20))
        self.username = toga.TextInput(placeholder='Username', style=Pack(color='gray', padding_top=200, padding_left=150), validators=list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789._-'))
        self.join_box.add(self.username)
        self.main_window.content = self.join_box
        self.main_window.show()


def main():
    return StartApp()


But the problem is that It's horizontal but it should be vertical.

Also I noticed that validators is making a problem.
Any ideas how to fix these?
Thanks!
